# Question about PBKDF salts and cryptographically secure randomness

Tags: pbkdf-2, salt, pbkdf

I have seen a few answers here and elsewhere that say a salt doesn't need to be cryptographically secure randomness but rather just unique since they are stored in the open anyway. I am working on an implementation of PBKDF2 and AES-CBC and reading ***NIST SP 800-132 Recommendation for Password-Based Key Derivation*** from 2010, it states in section 5 regarding salts:

> All or a portion of the salt **shall** be generated using an **approved** Random Bit Generator
> (e.g., see [5]). The length of the randomly-generated portion of the salt **shall** be at least
> 128 bits.

I don't personally care whether it needs excellent randomness or not but I just want to get it cleared up for my own sake whether the NIST recommendation contradicts that salts don't need to be cryptographically secure.

Answer (score 1):

In cryptography books, a salt is defined as a random value, but it technically only needs to be unique. See, for instance, the [Argon2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9106.html):

> The salt SHOULD be unique for each password.

The reason CSPRNGs are used is because they generate unique values with negligible chance of collision if you request a large enough output (e.g. 128 bits). By contrast, regular PRNGs and other strategies (e.g. a username or full name) may be predictable and/or lead to repetition.

Therefore, if you want to randomly generate salts, they should be cryptographically secure. If you can't use random salts (e.g. a [deterministic password manager](https://spectre.app/)), a non-cryptographically secure salt is fine as long as it's unique.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will take this that salts don't need to be cryptographically secure.

Comment: That's correct, although you should use a CSPRNG for random salts. I will clarify my answer slightly.